# If f(w) = log(sigmoid(w^T*x)) calculate the gradient (d/dw) of f(w)

Tags: machine-learning, regression, artificial-intelligence, calculus, sigmoid

w is an (nx1) vector and X is an (nxn) matrix. Here's my work: 
[image]

However this site (http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) says that the derivative should be [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ***Please*** review [ask], as well as look at the [help/on-topic] before asking further questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solutions are actually the same, if you take my (the first one) solution and expand it out with a common denominator you will get the second solution.